# No Pattern Interface Error with many methods in UIA backend

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to automate a rather old game client using pywinauto. I've had some success using the default win32 backend, but the uia backend can see more control identifiers, so I am attempting to rewrite the current automation with uia instead. Unfortunately, I have noticed that there seems to be less functionality with UIA. For example, I can only click_input, as there is no silent click. The bigger problem I have been having though is calling any method that requires an iface, as I get the error "NoPatternInterface".

For example, I am attempting to call get_selection() as a method of a ListItemWrapper, and it returns the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Q30.png).

Any Advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm thinking not to provide these methods if the action pattern iface is not supported (or create workarounds inside these methods). Is this app available publicly? It would be easier to find a workaround.

Comment: No, it is not publicly available, it is just a project I'm doing for fun. I currently do have a work around, but I was attempting to rewrite it to use the uia backend, as it seems to see more of the program. I'm more curious in my there is no iface found, and if possible, how I can set an iface for the program, rather than just finding a work around.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your own app with all sources, you can implement UI Automation provider for this control class. It's out of scope for pywinauto because providers are often implemented on app side. Some guidance could be found in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671615.aspx) or somewhere else. This is a kind of challenge.

P.S. I would be interested in examples for the most common apps like WinForms or WPF so that we can provide a short reference in pywinauto docs.

Comment: Thanks for the link! So unfortunately, the app I am trying to automate is not my own, and I do not have access to the source code for that. Is it possible to add the UI Automation provider without changing the source code?

Comment: Client-side providers are also possible to implement. But I have no such an experience.